# Redirect all page on a domain to one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am looking to  permanently redirect all the pages on a domain to one page on the SAME domain, using htaccess/mod_rewrite.

Basically I want any page requested for the domain to return a holding page [ which is index.php] at domain.com/

most of my attempts so far are causing errors as they are throwing the server intoa loop.

Thanks in advance

.k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,

got it working, here it is it might be of help to others:

RewriteRule !^(index.php)|.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|mp3|xml|swf)$ /index.php [L,R=301]

.k

Answer (score 3):

You need to exclude the destination you are redirecting to like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

If you just want to redirect requests that can not be mapped to existing files in the filesystem, add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

But you should rather respond with a 404 in that case.

Comment: thanks for that Gumbo,

but that redirect everything [css and image] I just want to redirect the webpages

Comment: @Keet: And “the webpages” are what?

Comment: What I meant was if a webpage /some/old/page.html was requested, index.php would be returned. 
but that page require other files  ie images/js/css etc. in this case i don't want index.php to be returned !

Comment: @Keet: And how can those URLs be identified?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php
```

And a bit more sophisticated one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Both were taken from [Zend Framework Zend_Controller Programmer's Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html). Here's another useful doc [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that first one seems to work, but it seem to display the new page with original page name ?  just one question do you know how to change this to a 301 that redirects to the new page, i tried adding [L,R=301] to the end of the line but it breaks it .

Comment: Frankly speaking, Keet, I don't really get what are you trying to accomplish with forcing the actual redirect. Adding `R=301` flag means telling the your Apache server to ALWAYS force redirect all the requests to `index.php`, which BTW is a request itself and gets redirected again and again again. Browser simply ends up in an indefinite loop, which of course totally breaks the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

ISR that this was asked here recently - but I can't find the q right now.

Why not just set up the 404 errorhandler to point to the holding page (and keep all other content out of the doc root)

C.

Comment: @symcbean surely returning 404 is not the best in this situation [SEO?]
All the old pages have pagerankings. by returning 301's these should be changes to the new page afaik